# How to keep facebook login without browser alive in .NET?

Tags: .net, facebook

I am logging in to facebook using a HTTPWebRequest in .NET, it works fine returning home.php logged in, but if I try to load another page it does not do it as logged in.

I have tried saving the cookie from the home return but still does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

I have the following code:

```
try
    {
        //Get Cookies
        strURL = "https://login.facebook.com/login.php";
        request =(HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL);
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.648.204 Safari/534.16";


        request.Method = "GET";
        request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        foreach (System.Net.Cookie tempCookie in response.Cookies)
        {
            cookieJar.Add(tempCookie);
        }

        //Send the post data now
        request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL);
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.648.204 Safari/534.16";

        string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
        writer.Write("email=xxx@gmail.com&pass=xxx&persistent_inputcheckbox=on");
        writer.Close();
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        CookieContainer loggedInCookies = new CookieContainer();
        foreach (Cookie tempCookie in response.Cookies)
        {
            loggedInCookies.Add(tempCookie);

        }
        //Get the data from the page
        StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string data = stream.ReadToEnd();
        response.Close();

        if (data.Contains("<title>Facebook") == true)
        {
            //LOGGED IN SUCCESSFULLY
        }
        return loggedInCookies;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: This is totally not a way you should be handling Facebook! That's what Facebook API is for!

Comment: I know there is an api but for what I am trying to do there is nothing in the API... that is why I am trying to find a work around...

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I don't know any situation where developer can't do something trough API (either FQL or Graph) and user can do it using web interface.

Comment: I am building an application that blocks all apps, or selected apps.

Comment: @DrMcKay there are things the API can't do, like, accept login+password and Just Do It. Instead they pop up the login window. Not exactly what you want in automated testing scripts...